# QGIS - automatically complete habitat codes based on name

Tags: qgis, widget

In a QGIS (3.22) form, I try to automatically complete habitat codes when I enter a habitat name. For this, I have a csv Table with the codes `btcode` and the names `btname`.

btcode | btname 
1.1    | name1 
1.2    | name2 
1.3    | name3

As widget type in the form, I use value relation in both cases (see the images for detailed settings). When I enter the `btname` I want to automatically populate the `btcode` field with the corresponding code. I am able to select the `btnames` in the dropdown (using the completer) and the `btcodes` separately. However, I struggle with automatic updating the `btcode`. I use the filter expression `"btname"  = current_value('btname')`, but it does not populate the code field. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are both screenshots showing the  same attribute form, or different ones. How do you expect the attribute form to behave?

Comment: Correct, the screenshots show the same attribute form. When I enter the btname I want to automatically populate the btcode field. Both value relations refer to the same csv file.